# Java Itext PDF - Can I change the input line of the AcroFields?

Tags: java, itext

I'm Currently mapping a PDF form using itextpdf, version: 5.5.13.1
Problem: When I edit the mapped PDF using any editor as Acroba Pro or Foxit, the field text line change.

Q: Can I make the mapping line-height the same as the PDF editors.

Edit: Below two screenshots, you can see when I edit the field the line-height change. I added the line under the text to show the difference.

Before the edit ==> 
[image] 
After the edits ==> 
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I also do not understand your question. Can you add some screenshot where you explain your issue? With mapping line do you mean the border around the field?

Comment: I added two screenshots to show the difference.